# Input from file and saving output in file

Tags: java, file, java-io

I am not being able to print all the output in file.BufferedWriter is not working well.What is my mistake to save the output of the program in file.

```
public class delete {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int alphabet=0;
        char ch;
        int n=0; 
        String line;        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("InputFileLocation"));
        line= br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++){

                  ch=line.charAt(i);
                            if(ch=='a')
                                alphabet ++;
              }

                            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("OutputFileLocation"));
                            n++;    
                            System.out.println("case#"+n+":"+alphabet);
                            bw.write(String.valueOf(alphabet));
                            bw.close();
                            alphabet=0;

        }
        br.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without running this I notice that you discard the first line by retrieving it, then retrieving another line in the first run of your condition.

Also, if you are writing every line to the output file then you probably want to move your initialization of bw outside your while loop.  At the very least you want to use the FileWriter(String, boolean) constructor instead of creating a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Dont create new BufferedWriter in the loop, thats a bad design.

you could try putting bw.flush() before closing it.

bw.close() implicitly call flush, but I had similar problem with this, I had to call flush explicitly to work.